# determinant of a $2\times2$ matrix, sufficiency of inverse

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

What is the simplest example of a nontrivial ring in which these two conditions are not equivalent for any $2\times 2$ matrix $A$:

(1) there is a $2\times2$ matrix $B$ with $A\cdot B=1$

(2) $a_{11}a_{22}\neq a_{21}a_{21}$

To make the question more interesting: can the structures such that (1) is (not) equivalent to (2) be characterized?

Answer (score 1):

Condition (2) as written is not equivalent to invertibility of a matrix over any (commutative) ring and it should be
$$
a_{11}a_{22}\ne a_{12}a_{21}
$$
A truly equivalent condition is that the determinant is invertible in the ring, so it shouldn't be really difficult to find an example over the simplest ring which is not a field.

Comment: It is not the truly equivalent condition. This weaker one is truly equivalent, the determinant must be ***right*** invertible only, right?

Comment: @user122424 Are we talking about a commutative ring?

Answer (score 0):

Try $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}\in M_2(\mathbb{Z}_4)$. (2) doesn't imply (1) for the reason that $2$ is no invertible. Just as mentioned before by @egreg

Comment: You meant $(\mathbb Z/4)$, right?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

for 
$$
a_{11}a_{22}\ne a_{12}a_{21}
$$
consider the subring of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ with matrices of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}&\mathbb{Q}\\
0&\mathbb{Z}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Many matrices with non null determinant are not invertible in this ring.

Answer (score 0):

A matrix $A\in M_2(R)$, where $R$ is a ring, is invertible iff $\det A\in U(R)$, where $U(R)$ is the set of the units of the ring $R$.

So a simple example is given by the ring $\Bbb Z$, any matrices whose determinant is different to $\pm 1$ is not invertible.

> Example 
>   $$ A=
> \begin{pmatrix}
> 2 & 1\\
> 3 & 4
> \end{pmatrix}
> $$
>
> $\det A=5$ so $A$ is not invertible in $M_2(\Bbb Z)$, even if is invertible in $M_2(\Bbb R)$.